# Insect race with celestial body on collision course with their planet, told over centuries

Tags: story-identification

A co-worker loaned me a book in the mid-nineties (it was not new) that followed the astronomers of a non-humanoid species. The story was spread across several centuries, as the astronomers discovered and finally convinced the rest of the planet that a huge celestial body was on a collision course with their planet.

I think he said it was out of print (I know he was desperate for me to return it). Another note, the balance of power between the males and females of species varied wildly across the centuries as the species' scientific knowledge increased. I've googled this in every way I can imagine and I've come up empty.

Comment: It's almost certainly The Crucible of Time as answered below.  You should 'accept' that answer if it's correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [novel identification: alien scientists must save their civilization from future destruction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152708/novel-identification-alien-scientists-must-save-their-civilization-from-future)

Comment: @RoboticCat Although this looks to be correct, there is no acceptance (even verbally) from the OP, so we can't accept this as a dupe. See [relevant meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/21267) for details.

Comment: May well be *The Crucible of Time*, but we should close as a duplicate unless the OP agrees.

Answer (score 7):

[image: 1]

[The Crucible of Time](http://www.tor.com/2009/07/24/alien-stars-john-brunners-the-crucible-of-time/) by John Brunner.

The novel follows the events on an alien planet over several centuries. The planet is entering a nebula and the meteoritic bombardment will eventually destroy it. Will the aliens develop enough scientific knowledge to escape their world before it is too late?

Comment: *Shut up and take my money!!* I *so* have to read this